# Communicating between AppDelegate and SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swiftui, aws-amplify

I am attempting to implement a custom login UI with the AWS Amplify framework. I have successfully implemented the signIn() function, as follows:

```
public func signIn(username: String, password: String) {
        _ = Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: username, password: password) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(_):
                print("Sign in succeeded")
                // nothing else required, the event HUB will trigger the UI refresh
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Sign in failed \(error)")
                
                // in real life present a message to the user
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code has been placed in my AppDelegate file. Now what I would like to be able to do is to display a message to the user in my Login view when the sign has failed, but I do not know how to pass the error from the signIn() function into the login view. Here is the relevant part of my Login view class:

```
  let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                          
                            self.phoneField?.bindUserInputToPhoneNumber()
                            self.deleteWhitespaceAndParensFromUserInput()
                            
                            app.signIn(username: self.phoneNumber, password: self.password)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It does not look like SwiftUI code (no view classes), didn't you confuse topic with UIKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create some kind of model object that will hold this data for you. You can start with an `ObservableObject` that you will pass to your root `ContentView` (if you're continuining to use this from the template):

```swift
final class Model: ObservableObject {

  struct AuthStatus {
    case unknown
    case loggedIn(User) // or whatever your auth object/struct etc. is
    case error(Error)
  }

  @Published var authStatus: AuthStatus = .unknown
}
```

Now you can pass this to your `ContentView` a couple different ways, but one of the nicest for this kind of global state, is `EnvironmentObject`. Since you mentioned an `AppDelegate`, i'm assuming you're not using the new SwiftUI only app lifecycle code, which means you're using `UIHostingController`. Add the following in `AppDelegate`.

```swift
var window: UIWindow?
var model: Model = .init()
```

And then this should go in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` where you set up your root view controller.

```swift
window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(root:
   ContentView()
     .environmentObject(model)
)
```

Now your content view can just declare it wants this environment object:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var model: Model // swiftui will resolve this for you

  var body: some View {
    Text("Auth status: \(model.authStatus)")
  }
}
```

If you want to more easily differentiate errors etc, you may want to create an additional `@Published` var in your Model instead of combining then into an `enum` as I have done here.

Comment: This didn't work for me. First, I got an error "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'view:', expected 'rootView:')" so I changed view: to rootView: . Second, I got a "Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type NavigationManager found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for NavigationManager may be missing as an ancestor of this view." NavigationManager is my Model.